# Стрельба уникальными запросами

Tags: яндекс-танк

Задача: пострелять уникальными запросами. У каждого запроса есть заголовок, содержимое которого - подпись, рассчитываемая по определенному алгоритму из тела и заголовков запроса.

Подпись должна быть уникальной (организовывается за счет случайных данных в заголовке). Соответственно, каждый запрос тоже должен быть уникальным.

Вопрос: как это лучше всего организовать?

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта:

1. Использовать `yandex-tank` с дефолтным генератором нагрузки `phantom`. На
   вход танку подается файл с запросами, соответственно вам нужно его
   заранее сгенерировать (см.
   https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#request-style)
   Перед подачей нагрузки степпер танка готовит из него файлик
   ammo.stpd в котором указаны запросы с таймстемпом, говорящим когда
   патрон должен быть выстрелен (согласно заданному вами расписанию).
   Файл с запросами читается степпером последовательно.
   Если файл окончился, а схема требует еще патронов - степпер начнет читать файл  заново.
   По дефолту ограничений на число перечитываний нет (его можно задать опцией `phantom.loop` - есть в той же доке).
2. Создать сценарий в `jmeter`, где с помощью beanshell/jexl на лету
   создавать нужные заголовки. Сценарий при желании можно подключить к танку, в модуле `[jmeter]` https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#jmeter